# How can I do a money transfer from Lebanon to India for payment on a consulting project?

Tags: india, bank-account, money-transfer

I am an Indian citizen and hold a domestic account. I am doing a short term consulting project for a client in the Middle East and they will be paying me in $. The amount that will be transferred is less than $10,000. Can someone please advise me how to facilitate this transfer to my Indian account?

Answer (score 2):

Ask them to send a SWIFT payment [aka International Wire]. You would need to give them your bank details, essentially Bank Account, Bank Name & Address, SWIFT BIC, etc. Almost all Public Sector Bank and all leading Private scetor banks are members of SWIFT and can give you a the SWIFT BIC. If you are not sure about other party, it would be wise to open a new account and give the details of this account rather than your normal account.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand [TransferWise](https://transferwise.com/en)’s [Supported Countries page](https://transferwise.com/help/article/1570071/basic-information/supported-countries) correctly, you could use their service. I believe it should be cheaper than having the bank convert. I've been very happy with the service and use it regularly.